# Thinking Sphinx or condtion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

How do you use a `conditional or` in thinking sphinx?

The situation is:
I have a `Message` model with a sender_id and recipient_id attribute. I would like to compose this query:

```
  Message.where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", business_id, business_id)
```

Right now, I'm searching twice, one for all the messages that has recipient_id = business_id and another to return all messages that has sender_id = business_id. Then I just merge them.

I feel that there's a more efficient way to do this.

**EDIT** - Adding index file

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :message, with: :active_record, delta: ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
  # fields
  indexes body 

  # attributes
  has job_id
  has sender_id
  has recipient_id

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx doesn't allow for OR logic between attributes, only fields. However, a workaround would be to combine the two columns into a third attribute:

```
has [sender_id, recipient_id], :as => :business_ids, :multi => true
```

And then you can search on the combined values like so:

```
Message.search :with => {:business_ids => business_id}
```

Comment: Thanks Pat for the reply but when I tried the workaround, it's only searching for all the messages with `sender_id` = business_id

Comment: Is the index SQL-based, or real-time?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by an SQL-based or real-time index? If it helps, i'll post the index file.

Comment: In your index you've got `with: :active_record`, which means the generated index is populated via SQL queries. (Real-time indices, on the other hand, are populated via Ruby and the context of your Rails app.)

Comment: It turns out my suggestion was missing a setting: `:multi => true` - which informs Sphinx that the attribute has multiple values (and thus, both the sender and recipient ids). Give that a shot, let me know if it doesn't work.